# "getUserMedia" not working in Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 m

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, getusermedia

I was following the tutorial for audio GUM with [this](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Live-Web-Audio-Input-Enabled) HTML5Rocks post. Here is the code:

```
function gotStream(stream) {
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    var audioContext = new AudioContext();

    // Create an AudioNode from the stream.
    var mediaStreamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource( stream );

    // Connect it to the destination to hear yourself (or any other node for processing!)
    mediaStreamSource.connect( audioContext.destination );
}

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true}, gotStream,function(e){console.log(e);});
```

I tried running this in Chrome, but absolutely nothing happened. No errors, or anything. The "asking for permission" dialog did not show up either.

I'm using Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 m.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, works fine for me.  Can you confirm in the top right corner of chrome you don't see a red 'x' indicating its blocking the connection.

Comment: Can't see anything, thanks for taking the time for testing this out. Here's a screenshot of my Chrome. `http://i.imgur.com/ncZGejk.png?1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access your ../*.html file directly.  Chrome won't correctly for a number of features due to the **Same Origin Policy**. There are two solutions.

1. Set up a simple http server.  You can do this by enabling apache to serve your local files for you.
2. Disable same origin policy for chrome.

A quick google for both will turn up several full detailed examples on how to do either.  I would suggest option 1 because this will emulate how your webpage will behave when it is live.